# react & highcharts: get a pointer to the React component in which the Highchart pie is drawn from the event function

Tags: reactjs, function, highcharts, binding

Please advise how to solve the following problem:

There is a React component in which the Highcharts pie is rendered. Need to monitor clicking on a sector of the pie and call a React component method.

```
events: {
    click: function(event: Highcharts.SeriesClickCallbackFunction) {
               this.setState({id: event.pointerId}); // ERROR - 'this' of local function, not component 
           }    
}
```

how do I access the parent component from a function?

When I use 'this', I access the local function

how do I pass a pointer to a component in a function?

**code:**

```
class MyChart extends Component<IProps_Chart, IState_Chart> {

    constructor(
        props: IProps_Chart
    ) {
        super(props);

        Highcharts.setOptions(theme);

        const pieOptions: any = this.props.compact ? {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie'
            },
            series: [{
                data: this.props.data,

                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function(event: Highcharts.SeriesClickCallbackFunction) {
                            this.setState({id: event.pointerId}); // ERROR - 'this' of local function, not component 
                        }
                    }
                }                
            }]
        };

        this.state = {
            options:       pieOptions
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
<HighchartsReact
    options = {this.state.options}
    highcharts = {Highcharts}
/>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

completed:

in Highcharts pie:

```
point:{
    events:{
        click: this.test.bind(this)
    }
}
```

in React component:

```
test = (event: any) => {
    console.error(this.props.data[event.point.index]);
}
```